# Prove the following

Tags: linear-algebra

Prove that if $p$ and $q$ are polynomials over the field $F$, then the degree of their sum is less than or equal to whichever polynomial's degree is larger

$$\deg(p+q)\leq \max \left\{\deg(p),\deg(q) \right\}$$

Currently, I am taking it case by case, but I was curious if there was a way to do a proof by contradiction.  What would it mean if I could add $2$ polynomials the result would be of larger degree than either of them.

Comment: What you're describing is impossible by the way polynomial rings are constructed.

Comment: Do you mean it is unprovable?  I don't think so.  It is conceptually easy to see.

The degree will either be the largest, the smallest, or the degree of the zero polynomial.

Comment: Careful. If $F=\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$, what happens when you add $x^2+x+1$ and $x^2 + 1$?

Comment: I'm not really sure.  This is a first course in proof and linear algebra.

Comment: @DemetriP I think Ian was (correctly) stating that your last sentence ("What would it mean...") is describing something that's impossible. The proof is actually trivial, since polynomial is represented by a sequence of elements of the field (its coefficients).

Comment: Mmm, I agree.  I was just wondering if I could use proof by contradiction to make the proof a little shorter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's one way. Let $\, \rm d := \deg.\,$ Suppose for contradiction $\, {\rm d}(f+g) > {\rm d}(f),\, {\rm d}(g).\,$ Choose such a counterexample of  minimal degree $\,d = {\rm d}(f+g).\,$ Necessarily $\,d > 0\,$ since it is true for constants. Since $(f+g)(0) = f(0)+g(0)\,$ subtracting the constant terms from $f,g$ then cancelling $x$ from both yields a counterexample of smaller degree, contra the minimality hypothesis.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: write polynomials in their general forms, and look at what happens when you sum them. It is impossible to create a nonzero coefficient where the coefficient was zero before, so in particular you cannot augment the maximal degree.